# Is there is a function in system verilog that can return the number of the most significant bits of an array

Tags: verilog, system, fpga, hdl

iam trying to get the number of the effective bits in an array
for example:
if i have an array that contains these sequence of bits:
0000_0101
the dimension of the array is 8 , i just want way to get the number of the most significant bits which are 3 in this case

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that behaves as described in the post:

```
module tb ();
  
  reg [7:0] temp;
  reg [7:0] myvector;
  
  function automatic int returns_location(input reg [7:0] vector);
    integer val = 0;
    for(int i =0;i < $size(vector);i++)
        if(vector[i]== 1'b1)
          val = i;
    return (val + 1);
  endfunction
  
  initial
    begin
      // From the post
      temp = 8'b0000_0101;
      $display("---- location of most sig 1 = %0d ----",returns_location(temp));
      #1;
      // Another example, shift 1 left
      temp = 8'b0000_1101;
      $display("---- location of most sig 1 = %0d ----",returns_location(temp));
      #1
      // Another example, shift 2 left
      temp = 8'b0001_1101;
      $display("---- location of most sig 1 = %0d ----",returns_location(temp));
      #1      
      $finish;
    end
    
endmodule
```

And produces the results:

```
# ---- location of most sig 1 = 3 ----
# ---- location of most sig 1 = 4 ----
# ---- location of most sig 1 = 5 ----
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're looking for number of bits enough to index into an 8b vector.

Assuming your variable (reg, logic) is named arr[]
You could use: **$clog2($bits(arr))**

Here $bits(arr) would be 8.
Then clog2(8) will be 3. This takes care of non-power of 2 widths also.

Edit: changed from clogb2() to clog2().

Comment: your answer would be valid only in this specific example but it couldn't be used as a general solution

Comment: there is no `$clogb2`, I think you meant `$clog2`

Comment: @Greg you're right.

Comment: @SamuelMikhael: can you please elaborate? I believe it would work for any variable.

Comment: The post is asking for the bit index (1-based) of the most significant bit within a defined vector size.  For example given an 8 bit vector and the number 0000_0001, 1 is the answer.  Given 8 bit vector and 0000_0011, 2 is the answer, given 0000_0111 3 is the answer, given 0001_1010 5 is the answer, given 0010_<anything> 6 is the answer, given 0100_anything_7 is the answer, and given 1000_0000, 8 is the answer.  The post asks for a Verilog built-in; there is none, however we cane write a function that does this.  This could be considered of the number of used bits or most significant bits.